# how to show a div when click on a anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, codeigniter

I am working on bus booking website. There are many bus operators lists. When click on book now link, i need to show that particular bus information just below of that row only. In every list i have Book now button. please check my html code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ltbrd").click(function(){
     $(this).find(".bcont").slideToggle(200);
  });
 
});
```

```css
.busrowmain {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.busrow {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    width: 940px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.busrow li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 42px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#444;
}

.busrow li span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.busrowbtn {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.busrowbtn a {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    background: #da4f56;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.busrowbtn a:hover {
    background: #f15a61;
}

.ltbrd {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.ltbrd:hover {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.bcont {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-top: solid 2px #e8e8e8;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row ltbrd">
 <div class="busrowmain">
  <div class="busrow">
   <li> BUS NO <br/>
    <span>TN045</span>
   </li>
   <li> BUS TYPE <br/>
    <span>2*3 AC</span>
   </li>
   <li> DEPARTURE TIME <br/>
    <span>10:00 PM</span>
   </li>
   <li> ARRIVAL TIME <br/>
    <span>2:00 AM</span>
   </li>
   <li> SEATS <br/>
    <span>62</span>
   </li>
   <li> FARE <br/>
    <span>750</span>
   </li>
  </div>
  <div class="busrowbtn">
   <a href="#">BOOK NOW</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="bcont"> Bus Information content </div>
</div>
```

When i click on bus list row, bus information section is opening. But I need when we click on book now link then only open the bus information div. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".busrowbtn a").click(function(){
      $(this).parents(".busrowmain").next(".bcont").slideToggle(200);
  });
 
});
```

```css
.busrowmain {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.busrow {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    width: 940px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.busrow li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 42px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#444;
}

.busrow li span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.busrowbtn {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.busrowbtn a {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    background: #da4f56;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.busrowbtn a:hover {
    background: #f15a61;
}

.ltbrd {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.ltbrd:hover {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.bcont {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-top: solid 2px #e8e8e8;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ltbrd">
          <div class="busrowmain">
            <div class="busrow">
              <li> BUS NO <br>
                <span>TN045</span></li>
              <li> BUS TYPE <br>
                <span>2*3 AC</span></li>
              <li> DEPARTURE TIME <br>
                <span>10:00 PM</span></li>
              <li> ARRIVAL TIME <br>
                <span>2:00 AM</span></li>
              <li> SEATS <br>
                <span>62</span></li>
              <li> FARE <br>
                <span>750</span></li>
            </div>
            <div class="busrowbtn"> <a href="#">BOOK NOW</a> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bcont"> Bus Information content </div>
        </div>
```

Just trigger the click function on the `Book Now` button and then find the parent element using `parents()` function and shows the next content of it.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/show/

you can use $.show() and $.hide() for this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#div_id').show();">Book Now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using slide toggle function in your Jquery you can always use to separate functions like show() and hide() this will work .